# Air density decreases as temperature increases - but air also gets cooler as it expands; does this create a feedback loop?

Tags: altitude, density-altitude, meteorology

First, I apologize for the sloppy title. I had a tough time phrasing this as a concise question.

For a column of air at a given pressure, density decreases (the air expands) as temperature increases.

At the same time, however, adiabatic cooling seems to represent the opposite phenomenon. As a parcel of air rises, it expands due to a decrease in ambient pressure. This expansion results in fewer collisions between air molecules, thus its temperature decreases.

In other words, higher temperatures cause air to expand, but expansion causes air to cool. Does this result in a kind of feedback loop (i.e.: air expands, thus cools, thus contracts, thus warms, thus expands...), with temperature and density ultimately reaching a kind of equilibrium? Or are these two phenomena totally unrelated? Is there something else I'm misunderstanding altogether?

Thanks for any clarification and I hope this question makes sense!

Comment: I think this would be a better question for [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/). I don't see any relation to aviation.

Comment: @Bianfable Hmm, that may be fair. The question occurred to me through studying aviation weather theory, so this is where I thought to ask it.

Comment: [This answer on Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/40956) explains it; the error you've made is the reason for expansion. The answer also addresses the stratosphere where the temperature rises as you go higher. I also agree it's OT here. If the linked answer didn't help, you may want to ask a moderator to [migrate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249) the post over to Physics by raising a custom flag.

Comment: "*density decreases (the air expands) as temperature increases*" – yes, when you add energy while keeping pressure constant. That is how a hot air balloon works. If expansion is caused by reduced pressure, temperature **de**creases.

Comment: Under extreme conditions, such as a rocket exhaust, there may be something along the lines of your thinking in the form of the diamond pattern.  Not seen in weather as heating/cooling and volume changes are many orders of magnitude smaller.  See the SR-71 Blackbird jet exhaust.

Comment: @Bianfable, understanding the medium in which aircraft operate absolutely relates to aviation.  It is more relevant in my opinion than a lot of the database type questions we see here...

Comment: @MichaelHall Sure, we get a lot of questions about the atmosphere that are very important to aviation. But this one isn't! It is about basic physics (thermodynamic processes, ideal gas law) without any relation to aviation.

Comment: @Bianfable -- this is totally related to aviation, especially soaring.  Every glider pilot would be interested to know about it, if a chunk of atmosphere tended to start "boinging" up and down (insert appropriate noises from Wiley Coyote and Roadrunner cartoon here) due to the mechanism proposed in the original question.  Could make for an "interesting" flight--\

Comment: Appreciate the meta-engagement generated by this question. For what it's worth, I was asking the question totally from a place of curiosity and just trying to better understand weather theory, and not because I thought it would have any immediate practical benefit to my flying. But it did definitely strike me as an "aviation" question, which I was asking because I'm a student pilot.

Comment: @EthanB a look at an atmospheric temp profile would help.  What helps drive rising air is the *surrounding air* is progressively colder and thinner as you go up.  With or without cloud formation (which helps it keep rising), most thermals away from their heat source will radiate their higher temperature away and dissipate into the surrounding air.  Any oscillation in the downward temperature pattern, if measurable, may make an interesting study.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*density decreases (the air expands) as temperature increases*" – yes, when you add energy while keeping pressure constant. That is how a hot air balloon or a thermal works. If expansion is caused by reduced pressure, temperature **de**creases.

What happens in the atmosphere is normally described as an [isentropic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isentropic_process) process.

Comment: I think this is the relevant point I'm looking for. When energy is added and pressure remains constant, the temperature increases and the air expands. But because the pressure is constant in this case, there isn't a subsequent adiabatic decrease in temperature, so the infinite regress or feedback loop suggested in my original question does not occur. Correct me if I'm wrong or misunderstanding.

Comment: @EthanB Yes, that's it. It helps to ask yourself whether a process would need the addition or removal of energy and where this should come from.

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 players in your question, found in:

> the gas equation P = nR/V × T, and relative humidity

For your question:

> Density decreases as temperature increases

we can see lower density (nR/V) and higher temperature T will yield **the same pressure and a greater volume**.

> Higher temperature causes the air to expand

The air parcel is now lighter than the surrounding air and rises.

> But expansion causes the air to cool

The "contraction" is only due to temperature decrease.  With no change in pressure, no energy is going *into* the system to drive heating through compression. (Remember rising air is constantly moving into lower pressure). The contraction will be a thinning of the rising air column, as seen with the "classic" mushroom or anvil cloud.  It is simply a reduction in volume as temperature drops, with pressure remaining equal to surrounding air.

All fine and good until:  relative humidity gets too high. Moist air cools with expansion at a lower rate than dry air, and the lighter water vapor also contributes to its bouyancy.

Now the air rises much faster and higher, potentially leading to a thunderstorm.

> ultimately reaching a kind of equilibrium

So, yes, with weather the phenomena are related through pressure, and humidity plays a key role.  **Dry air, heavier than surrounding air of equal pressure but higher humidity, can be heated by compression as it sinks**.  These are the famous Chinook or Foehn winds.  As the dry air sinks, **the surrounding air of higher pressure compresses it**.  This is the opposite of adiabatic cooling.

Comment: Correct!  See edits.